# PHP ftp_put() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given when trying to upload a file to a remote ftp server

Tags: php, centos8

I'm trying to upload a submitted CV from job applicants to a remote ftp server.

I've wrapped all the steps into "if...else echo" statements and they are all successful (fopen, ftp_connect, ftp_login), but it gets stuck at the fpt_fput statement with this error:

> ftp_put() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/*******/phpmailer/sendmail.php on line 286

I've checked whether it could be SELinux, but it's not running on that server.

Here is the code for that section in the php file:

```
$location = "uploads/" . $finalCV;
//move_uploaded_file($_FILES['applCV']['tmp_name'], $location);

//Move uploaded & renamed CV to server
if($fp = fopen($location, 'r'))
  echo "File Open Successful. ";
  else {
    echo "File Open Unsuccessful. ";
  }

if($conn_id = ftp_connect("some.server"))
  echo "FTP Connection Established Successfully. ";
else {
  echo "FTP Connection Failed. ";
  }

$ftpuser = "wynand";
$ftppasswd = "********";

if($login = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpuser, $ftppasswd)) {
  echo "FTP Login Successful. ";
}
 else {
   echo "FTP Login Unsuccessful. ";
 }

if(ftp_put($login, $location, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded CV. ";
}
  else {
    echo "There was a problem uploading CV. ";
  }
```

Comment: `ftp_login` returns a true/false for the login, which cannot be used for the identifier. You need to use the `$conn_id` resource identifier instead.

Comment: If you find some troubles using the native functions you want to use an FTP client library to make things easier for you, I suggest this one for you. https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$login` have result `ftp_login()`, but `ftp_put()` want `resource $ftp`

Exemple from doc [ftp_put](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php)

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = 'readme.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
   echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
   echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

First param of `ftp_put()` take **`ftp_connect()`** result. Try

```
if(ftp_put($conn_id, $location, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded CV. ";
}
```

If you want use open file pointer on the local file (in your code you use it:)) try **`ftp_fput()`**

Comment: That seems to have worked, because now it gives:

ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path, resource given in /var/www/****/phpmailer/sendmail.php on line 286

Comment: Oh, i see just now.. you need change `ftp_put` on `ftp_fput`. If you use stream **($fp = fopen($location, 'r'))**..